# Сортировка правил в CSS по БЭМ

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, бэм, gulp-concat

В своем проекте я использую методологию БЭМ совместно с `gulp`. Таск для `css` выглядит следующим образом:

```
gulp.task('css', function(done) {
    gulp.src(['src/assets/css/global/*.css', 'src/assets/css/blocks/*.css'])
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: errorNotify}))

    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('prod/assets'))
    .on('end', function() {
        gulp.series('reload')();
        done();
    });
});
```

У меня несколько упрощенная иерархия файлов: всего один файл на блок, все его элементы, модификаторы, и модификаторы элементов. Все работает до тех пор, пока я не начинаю использовать миксы.

Предположим, у меня есть некоторый блок `"search"` со свойством `"border-color: white"`, и элемент `"header__search"` со свойством `"border-color: black"` в соответствующих файлах `"header.css"` и `"search.css"`. Естественно, в такой ситуации должно отдаваться предпочтение элементу `"header__search"`. Но на выходе содержимое `"header.css"` оказывается перед содержимым `"search.css"`, и получается, что у элемента с обоими классами белая граница вместо черной.

Решение я вижу следующим образом: на выходе разместить правила в порядке: "все блоки - все элементы - все модификаторы". Вопрос: как это сделать? В смысле, есть ли какие-либо готовые решения для такого? Соответствующих плагинов я не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готовых решений я так и не нашел, поэтому написал свое.

По сути, нужно осуществить поиск правил по регулярному выражению, удалить их и вставить в соответствующее место в файле. Порядок должен быть следующий: "блок - модификатор блока - элемент - модификатор элемента". 
Есть еще один важный момент: сортировка будет проходить по последнему классу в селекторе. Например, селектор ".block_mod .block__element path" будет считаться элементом, а селектор ".block__element + .block" - блоком. Для начала, разберемся с регулярными выражениями.

Выражение поиска любых комбинаций селектора (или же @-правила) и набора свойств. Первая и вторая группа - селектор и набор свойств соответственно. Между ними может быть сколько угодно пробелов и переносов строк:

```
/([^{}]+?)\s*{([\s\S]*?)}/g
```

Выражение поиска блока. Первая группа - все, что находится до искомого нами блока. Вторая группа - сам блок. Утверждение в конце означает, что после искомого блока не должно быть объявлено других классов, а также блок действительно является блоком, а не модификатором:

```
/(.*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(?!.*?[._])/
```

Выражение поиска элемента. Тут все аналогично выражению для блока, за исключением разделения двумя подчеркиваниями:

```
/(.*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9-]+__[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(?!.*?[._])/
```

Выражение поиска модификатора блока. Первая группа - аналогично блоку. Вторая группа - это возможный элемент (ведь модификатор может быть как у блока, так и у элемента). Третья группа - аналогично второй у элемента. Утверждение также аналогично утверждению у блока, только теперь нет проверки на модификатор:

```
/(.*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9-]+_[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(?!.*?\.)/
```

Выражение поиска модификатора элемента. Аналогично выражению для модификатора элемента, за исключением разделения двумя подчеркиваниями:

```
/(.*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9-]+__[a-zA-Z0-9-]+_[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(?!.*?\.)/
```

Еще есть @-правило, но для них не нужно регулярное выражение, достаточно только проверить, есть ли там "@":

```
selector.search('@') !== -1
```

Что касается плагинов, то тут нужен только плагин, который позволит читать и писать файлы. Можно вообще использовать fs, но я же предпочел gulp-insert.

Теперь нужно написать функцию, которая принимает содержимое css-файла в виде строки, и возвращает отсортированный результат. Собственно, вот код данной функции:

```
function cssBemSort(contents) {
    // Здесь будут храниться части файла: блоки, элементы, и модификаторы соответственно
    let blocks = elements = modificators = '';

    // Ищем все комбинации селектора и набора свойств
    contents = contents.replace(/([^{}]+?)\s*{([\s\S]*?)}/g, function(match, selector, props) {
        // Если селектор вовсе и не селектор, а @-правило, рекурсивно обрабатываем его и возвращаем на место
        // Если это правило, содержащее другие правила, вроде @media, правила внутри будут отсортированы
        // Если же это что-то другое, то ничего страшного не произойдет - правила просто не будут найдены, и будет возвращена исходная строка
        if (selector.search('@') !== -1) {
            const sortedProps = cssBemSort(properties);
            return `${selector}{${sortedProps}}`;
        }

        // Добавляем совпадение к блокам
        else if (/.*\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?!.*?[._])/.test(selector)) {
            blocks += match;
        }
        // Добавляем совпадение к элементам
        else if (/.*\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+__[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?!.*?[._])/.test(selector)) {
            elements += match;
        }
        // Добавляем совпадение к модификаторам
        else if (/.*\.([a-zA-Z0-9-]+__)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+_[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?!.*?\.)/.test(selector)) {
            modificators += match;
        }

        // Если селектор не соответствует ничему из вышеперечисленного, ничего не трогаем
        else return match;
        // Вырезаем данную часть из исходного файла
        return '';
    });

    // Возвращаем результат в отсортированом порядке
    return contents + blocks + elements + modificators;
}
```

Осталось только дополнить таск:

```
gulp.task('css', function(done) {
    gulp.src(['src/assets/css/global/*.css', 'src/assets/css/blocks/*.css'])
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: errorNotify}))

    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    // Вызываем метод transform у плагина insert, который принимает callback
    // Важно вызвать его после concat, иначе отсортируется каждый файл по отдельности
    .pipe(insert.transform(cssBemSort))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('prod/assets'))
    .on('end', function() {
        gulp.series('reload')();
        done();
    });
});
```

Готово. К сожалению, я рядовой фронтендер, и не обладаю достаточными знаниями node.js, чтобы написать это в виде отдельного gulp-плагина. Так что будет неплохо, если кто-нибудь сделает такой плагин, если это вообще имеет смысл.